# CSS for horizontal box model in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

All I want is to create an "header" with few boxes inside (divs) and I want to display them horizontally, Like a tool bar.

so here's a basic CSS code,
Works fine on Chrome but not on firefox,

```
header{
    margin-bottom:1px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    box-orient:inline-axis;
    -moz-box-orient:inline-axis;
    position: fixed;
    top:1px;
    font: 20px bold;
    color:red;
    background:pink;
    min-width:100%;
    height:10%;
}
```

I know it must be something really basic but I've been stuck for hours over it.
What am I missing here?

Comment: What doesn't work? What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/zRYLX/2/

Comment: The fiddle you've added works fine for chrome, but again it won't show it properly on FF, (v20.0.1),   even though when inspecting the elements the horizontal rule does appears.

Comment: If you're using Flexbox, never use the properties from the old 2009 draft on their own.  Always make sure you're including the modern ones as well (see: https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6).

Comment: you could just use `float` http://jsfiddle.net/zRYLX/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flexbox implementation in Firefox is quite broken (at least it is for properties from the 2009 draft).  Basically, you can't float a flex container in Firefox, nor can you position it to either absolute or fixed.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649578

Comment: _“you can't float a flex container, nor can you position it to either absolute or fixed.”_ – which is (/should be) quite obvious, since those are positioning techniques that oppose each other.

Comment: These are bugs that specific to Firefox that cause the flex containers/items to misbehave.  I'm not suggesting that you use them together.

Comment: that's right, removing the "position:fixed" line fixed the problem, although now I have another problem....